# select() behavior with respect to broken pipe

Tags: sockets, select

I'm using `select()` call to read and write to sockets
How to detect whether the other end has closed the socket? Essentially how to detect the broken pipe when using `select()`?

Answer (score 1):

If socket was closed normally from other end, select will report `read` condition for the socket.  If connection was lost for some other reason, either `read` or `error` condition will be reported.

Comment: Means, When other end is closed normally, select() will wak up on read and when we try to read from the socket it will return EPIPE ?

Comment: No, when you read from socket, that is normally closed from other end, `read` will just return zero which means "end of file".